# Should i use multisite for my business?

Tags: multisite

Currently building a website for my photography business and need help deciding if i should be creating a multisite website or not, if not what do you suggest.

My situation is as followed, we do photography for the following:

- Wedding
- Product
- Business / Commercial

Now the division that we are getting the most work on is weddings and it will be our main website and main focus but we occasionally get Commercial work and would like to have a dedicated section or website for that in particular where we can put all of our work and projects on there as we have a few. please bare in mind we would like to showcase the two portfolios we have one is more industrial and the other is weddings so i wanted two different themes for the two versions the wedding with a white background bright colours and the industrial with black or dark gray background and darker colours.

So would a multisite website with for example the following:

```
www.example.com
www.commercial.example.com
```

be a good choice and having a top links bar or button there to direct people from the main website to the commercial be a good choice?

Comment: Perfect use case for multisite.  You don't want `www.commercial.website.co.uk`, instead it would be `commercial.website.co.uk`.  The main site can be `website.co.uk`, with a registrar CNAME pointer from www to that domain.  I would suggest not getting locked in to a specialized stack like bitnami for this, as the answer below suggests.  This is an easy/simple multisite config on any good hosting company that WP can run on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally love multisites, because you only need to make updates once on core, themes and plugins. It also saves on hosting charges and makes user management easier. It also keeps uploads, posts, pages and custom content separate.

I guess you question comes because of having sub-domains (e.g. weddings.website.co.uk) or sub-folders (e.g. website.co.uk/weddings). I hear that sub-domains load slower that subfolders. According to [the question on sub2.sub1.subdomain.domain.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/278295/subdomain-of-a-subdomain) your sub-domains can be www.commercial.website.co.uk or www.toys.commercial.website.co.uk as you wish. Most people prefer to make the URL as short as possible so that it's easier to remember.

With [Bitnami](https://bitnami.com/stack/wordpress) (Free) you may now have a multisite with separate domains (e.g. weddings.co.uk) controlled by one main website. You will need to run your own server for this ([Google Console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) or [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/)).

There's also [MainWP](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mainwp/) (Paid Extensions) which has you install WordPress separately on each domain and control with a main website. This will work with shared hosting.

Comment: Little issue i have is that i cant use sub folders as i have already an existing website for weddings so only sub domains are allowed accordording to the guide im reading. if for example i wanted www.example.com/commercial your saying the load speed would be faster? Apparently there are issues with links when it comes to using sub folders though.

Comment: Then I guess you have no option but to go the subdomain way. Just be sure to backup your website before diving into any decision.